# JavaScript setInterval on several threads

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a generic dictionary like so:
data holds a dictionary (key, value) pair:

```
for (var key in data) {
  var interval = setInterval(function () { 
    getProgress(key, data[key], interval) }, 2500); // get percent progress every sec.
  }
}
```

getProcess function that needs to execute for EACH data[key] item

```
    function getProgress(machineId, operationId, interval) {
        alert(machineId);
        $.post("@Url.Action("Status","Packages")", { 
            machineId: machineId, 
            operationId: operationId 
            }, function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    //blah blah...
                } else { 
                    clearInterval(interval); }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

For some reason only the LAST machineId get's setInterval. I need to have setInterval for EACH data item separately.

Comment: All of your callbacks are sharing the same `key` variable. You need to wrap your code in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

Comment: Javascript is completely single-threaded.

Comment: Wow @casperOne, just wow. It's a crime to iteratively write an answer now?

Comment: when I do :for (var key in data) { alert(key) .. key is different.

Comment: @ShaneKm that's not really the same thing at all, you are defining functions inside the loop, which are then being called long after the loop has executed. Whereas with alert, you are calling it right away while the loop is still going

Comment: Why are you setting an interval in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic for loop scoping problem. Each iteration of the for loop is executed in the same scope, so every function that is created inside the for loop access the same `key` variable.

Simple solution is to create a private scope for each iteration.

```
for ( var key in data ) {
    (function (key) {
        var interval = setInterval(function () { 
            // get percent progress every sec.
            getProgress(key, data[key], interval) 
        }, 2500); 
    })(key);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had face same problem when implement forEach loop on array of data. To overcome this problem I simple implement basic way of for loop.

```
for(var key;key<data.length;key++)
{
  var interval = setInterval(function () 
  { 
    // get percent progress every sec.
    getProgress(key, data[key], interval) 
  }, 2500);
}
```

Also like solution to create a private scope for each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

All of your callbacks are sharing the same `key` variable.

You need to wrap your code in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/):

```
for (var dontUse in data) {
    (function(key) {
        var interval = setInterval(function () { getProgress(key, data[key], interval) }, 2500); // get percent progress every sec.
    })(dontUse);
}
```